# PEP 479, map() and StopIteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

It appears that [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) (Change StopIteration handling inside generators) has brought many inconveniences. Example code of a zip equivalent( from python's 2.7 docs, slightly changed by myself):

```
def izip(*iterables):
   # izip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
   iterators = list(map(iter, iterables))
   while True: 
       yield tuple(map(next,iterators))
```

> zipper = izip([1, 2], [3, 4])
>
> next(zipper)
>
> (1, 3)
>
> next(zipper)
>
> (2, 4)
>
> next(zipper)
>
> ()
>
> next(zipper)
>
> ()

map() builtin generator swallows StopIteration raised by next() so zipper generator never ends. I can't even catch the exception inside izip because the problem resides inside map() itself. Is there any pythonic way to solve this without writing a custom map() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could check the length of `tuple` that you're going to `yield` and break the loop in case it's less than length of `iterators`:

```
def izip(*iterables):
    iterators = list(map(iter, iterables))
    while True:
        t = tuple(map(next,iterators))
        if len(t) != len(iterators):
            break
        yield t

zipper = izip([1, 2], [3, 4])
print(next(zipper)) # (1, 2)
print(next(zipper)) # (3, 4)
print(next(zipper)) # StopIteration
```